# Save Column Width and Order Info to Registry (MFC)

Tags: mfc, registry

For saving column order, I was thinking of using the `CSettingsStore` class to save and restore arrays of integers to and from the registry (arrays that I would use `CListCtrl::GetColumnOrderArray()` and `CListCtrl::SetColumnOrderArray()` to generate and set). But I have no idea if that's realistically possible, or what registry data type to use (`DWORD`? Stuff the `int`s into a string array and use multi-string?). Also, `CSettingsStore` requires a **string** path to open up keys, while `GetAppRegistryKey()` returns an **`HKEY`**, so I'm not sure how to even use `CSettingsStore` with my app.

I have 3 questions.

1. Will this approach be feasible for loading and saving of column information? Or is there an obviously simpler solution?
2. What data types should I use to store the column order arrays in the registry?
3. How can I convert an `HKEY` value to a `CString`? Or should I just look up my app's registry key and hardcode it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation would be to format the column-count and the index values as a string delimited by comma (like `5, 1, 3, 4, 2, 0`, the first number is column-count) and store it in the registry as `REG_SZ` with something like

```
AfxGetApp()->WriteProfileString(_T("Settings\\<ListControlName>"), _T("ColumnOrder"), sFormattedString);
```

You can load the string using `GetProfileString()` and use either `CStringT::Tokenize()` or the straight API `strtok_s()` functions to retrieve the values.

I used `"Settings\\<ListControlName>"` in case you need to store more values for each ListControl, like sort-order, for example. Otherwise, you could have just one registry section called `"Settings\\ColumnOrder"` and use `<ListControlName>` as the value-name.

Comment: I used your answer with minor tweaks, thanks! The problem I'm having now is that I'm calling `GetColumnOrderArray()` on `HDN_ENDDRAG` notifications, but apparently the column list order hasn't been updated at that point yet; it always returns the order from before the drag and drop operation. Any ideas when I should get the column order?

Comment: I added an [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18383093/get-column-order-mfc) about getting the column order: I'm having trouble :/